# Process TYPO3 9.2 Mail Spool via Scheduler

Tags: typo3, swiftmailer, spool

I've just tried out the spool feature that's been integrated in TYPO3 9.2, 
https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-core/master/en-us/Changelog/9.2/Feature-76349-IntegrateSwiftMailersSpoolTransportIntoTYPO3.html

I've configured the system according to the tutorial page and everything seems to work fine when invoking the spool processing manually, but I'm wondering why there is no Task that I can just run from the Scheduler. 
The amout of cronjobs I can run is limited with my hoster and I don't want to waste one on the Spooler.

Isn't there supposed to be a Task? Is something on my system just set up wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked my TYPO3 v9.5.16, and it's there. So, when you choose "Execute console commands" for Class, you should be able to see "swiftmailer:spool:send" in the Schedulable Command list.

Comment: Damn, I'm an idiot. I was looking it up under the Extbase Commands list. My brain must have been a bit mushy after a debugging session yesterday. Thanks.